# Make any calls to a function only compile in debug

Tags: vb.net, debugging, compilation

The `Debug` class is useful as it allows debugging code to be written without it needing to be removed on release since any calls involving the class isn't compiled then.

How do I make my own custom Module or Class which does the same? For example, I've written this:

```
Module MyDebug

    Sub print(ByVal msg As String)

        Debug.Print(Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") & " " & msg)

    End Sub
End Module
```

The only solution I can find is to use macros, but that seems to be ridiculous because I have to write something like:

```
#If DEBUG
MyDebug.Print("...")
#endif
```

at every point I need to debug in the code compared to the one-liner if I were to use `Debug.Print("...")`.

Comment: I found that debugging didn't necessarily work with Class Libraries, so related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983688/debugging-with-my-own-custom-class-libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to tag your methods with the `<Conditional>` Attribute.

```
Module MyDebug

    <Conditional("DEBUG")>
    Sub Print(ByVal msg As String)
        Debug.Print(Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") & " " & msg)
    End Sub
End Module
```

[MSDN ConditionalAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[Reference Source for Debug class that uses the attribute](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/diagnostics/Debug.cs,632c6da37ce825df)

Comment: Thank you — I shouldn't've missed that.

Comment: No worries. A lot of people don't realize it even exists. It can come quite handy at times.

Comment: Is it possible to tag a whole Module/Class?

Comment: According to the MSDN documentation, yes. Maybe not Module, but a Class, is definitely a yes.

Comment: I've just tested it out - it doesn't work for Modules. Definitely works for the function, not sure about the class — I'll have to work with it. Thanks!