# Debugging with my own custom Class Libraries

Tags: vb.net, debugging, class-library, conditional-compilation

I want my class library conditionally compiled so that it is in debugging mode when my project is, and is not when my project isn't.

For example, I have this Module in my class library:

```
Module MyDebug

    <Conditional("DEBUG")>
    Sub print(ByVal msg As String)
        Debug.Print(Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") & " " & msg)
    End Sub

    <Conditional("DEBUG")>
    Sub debugEnd(Byval bool As Boolean)

        Environment.Exit(0)
    End Sub
End Module
```

When I debug my project which references this library it run any of these when they are called.

I've tried searching online, but I haven't found anything that helps since I can only find things to do with debugging the actually class library, while I only want it to send these conditionally compiled statements while I'm debugging my project.

---

However, by experimenting around a bit, I've found that if in the class library I go to:

`'My Project' -> the 'Compile' tab -> 'Advanced Compile Options'`

and then tick 'Define DEBUG constant' (and then build the library), the project does run the debug statements when called.

However, I'm not entirely sure of the behaviour of 'Define DEBUG constant' in the class library. Does it define DEBUG if and only if my project is in debug mode?

If not, then is there a simple way to acheive what I aim to do? (I don't want to have to tick/untick the checkbox in the class library each time I switch between debug and release in my project, and my class library is referenced by more than one project, anyway)

---

Note that in the project I'm referencing the `.dll` in the `Bin -> Release` folder of my class library which I hope is the right way to reference it.

---

In addition, I would like to ask about how VB acheives this with the `Debug` class, because it is also imported with a reference like any other class library, and works in the way I would like the above to — surely I could do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep the class library project in the same solution as your main project it will use the same configuration (`Debug` or `Release`) as every other project in that solution. This means that you won't have to manually check/uncheck `Define DEBUG constant` as it will not be defined anyway if you have set the configuration to `Release`.

Even if your projects are not in the same folder you may still add your class library project to your solution. Here's how to do it:

1. Right-click your solution in the `Solution Explorer` and goto `Add > Existing Project`.
2. In the file browsing dialog that opens, locate the `.vbproj`-file of your class library and click `OK`.
3. Now when you change compilation configuration it should be reflected over the entire solution and your class library shall only have its `DEBUG` constant defined if you set the configuration to `Debug`.

**If you cannot see your solution in the `Solution Explorer`:**

1. In Visual Studio, goto `Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General`.
2. Check `Always show solution` and press `OK`.

---

For the above to work you must also change the way you reference your class library. The way you are currently doing it is correct, but it won't work in this case as then you'll only be referencing the `Release` version of your dll.

1. Start by removing your current reference to your class library.
2. Open the `Add Reference` dialog and go to the `Projects` tab.
3. Select your class library's project and press `OK`.

This should now reference the class library's output from the solution's current compilation configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the perfect solution for me as I can edit the 2 alongside each other as well, and breakpoints can be used too.

Comment: @QuestionAsker : Glad to hear! Visual Studio is greatly optimized and very user friendly. I recently started using this method myself, too (even if I've known it for years).